# Is there an efficient way to search a list with another list maintaining the list's order?

Tags: python, list

I am just starting to learn python.
I need to search one list with another but I have to maintain the order of the list i'm  searching with. EX:

```
MylistA = [A, B, G, S, X]

MylistB = [A, G, B]
```

I want this to return false as `ListB` isn't in the same order as `ListA`. However, if it was:

```
ListA =[A, B, G, S, X]
ListB =[A, B, G]
```

I would want this to return `True`.

The following is what I have tried however it takes up many lines and is inefficient.

```
MylistA = [A, Q, V, B, G, D, F, R, T, B, G, S, Q]
MylistB = [B, G, D, F, R, T]

ListFound = 0
Pos1 = 0
Pos2 = 1
Pos3 = 2
Pos4 = 3
Pos5 = 4
Pos6 = 5

Pos1A = 0
Pos2A = 1
Pos3A = 2
Pos4A = 3
Pos5A = 4
Pos6A = 5

while Pos6 <= len(MylistA):
    if MylistA[pos1] == MylistB[Pos1A] and \
            MylistA[pos2] == MylistB[Pos2A] and \
            MylistA[pos3] == MylistB[Pos3A] and \
            MylistA[pos4] == MylistB[Pos4A] and \
            MylistA[pos5] == MylistB[Pos5A] and \
            MylistA[pos6] == MylistB[Pos6A]:
        print("MylistB found within MylistA at positions", Pos1, Pos2, Pos3, Pos4,     
               Pos5, Pos6)
        MylistFound += 1
    elif Pos6 >= len(ListA):
        print("MylistB was found", ListFound, "times within MylistA") 
    Pos1 += 1
    Pos2 += 1
    Pos3 += 1
    Pos4 += 1
    Pos5 += 1
    Pos6 += 1
```

This works as expected however takes up many lines and I'm looking for an efficient method to achieve the same results. Thanks for the help.

Comment: "**This works as expected**": `ListA`and `ListB` aren't valid python lists, how did you manage to run the code?

Comment: Are your list elements always a string?

Comment: Do you want true or false for ListB = ['A', 'B', 'X']? The order is kept, but the ListB is distributed inside ListA in that case.

Comment: Yes they always stay as a string @kerwei

Comment: I would want that to be false as I need them to be in consecutive order @brevno

Comment: I have the same idea as the answer proposed by @FlorentJousse below, but do take note of my comments in her answers as well as that approach comes with caveats!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create something like:

```
ListA = ["A", "Q", "V", "B", "G", "D", "F", "R", "T", "B", "G", "S", "Q"]
ListB = ["B", "G", "D", "F", "R", "T"]

for x in range(0, len(ListA)):
    if ListA[x:len(ListB)+x] == ListB:
        print("Full Match", ListA[x:len(ListB)+x])
        print("Positions", "{}:{}".format(x, len(ListB)+x))
        break

# Full Match ['B', 'G', 'D', 'F', 'R', 'T']
# Positions 3:9 # last value (9) is exclusive
```

---

[Demo](https://ideone.com/PhzaNK)

Comment: I've tried this and it works nicely thanks. How would I also be able to highlight at which positions the match is found?

Comment: You're welcome @Kimono1. Sure, I update the answer to reflect your comment. Thank you for being a *good citizen* and accepting the correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

```
def compare(lst_a, lst_b):
    try:
        temp = [lst_a.index(x) for x in lst_b]
    except ValueError:
        res = False
    else:
        res = temp == sorted(temp)
    return res
```

Some test runs:

```
ListA = ['A', 'B', 'G', 'S', 'X'] 
ListB = ['A', 'G', 'B']
ListC = ['A', 'B', 'G']
ListD = ['A', 'B', 'FOO']

print(compare(ListA, ListB))  #-> False
print(compare(ListA, ListC))  #-> True
print(compare(ListA, ListD))  #-> False ('FOO' does not exist at all in ListA)
```

---

This works by getting the index of all entries in `ListB` from `ListA` and storing them on a new list `temp`. If `temp` is sorted (`temp == sorted(temp)`), then your rule has been respected, otherwise not.

Comment: `IndexError` or `ValueError`?

Comment: @Poolka nicely caught. Updated. Thanks!

Comment: What if `ListA = ['A', 'B', 'X', 'S', 'G']`? I guess result will be the same. Is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections 

inputList1 = [1, 2, 4, 3, 5] 
inputList2 = [1, 2, 4, 3, 5] 
print ("The first list is : " + str(inputList1)) 
print ("The second list is : " + str(inputList2)) 

# Using Sorting
inputList1.sort() 
inputList2.sort() 
if inputList1 == inputList2: 
    print ("The lists are identical") 
else : 
    print ("The lists are not identical")

# using Collection Counter  
if collections.Counter(inputList1) == collections.Counter(inputList2): 
    print ("The lists are identical") 
else : 
    print ("The lists are not identical")
```

Comment: This will not preserve order

Answer (score 0):

You could try to check the index of each element of ListB in ListA and after that check if they are in the right order:

```
ListA = ["A","Q","V","B","G","D","F","R","T","B","G","S","Q"]
ListB = ["B","G","D","F","R","T"]

indices=[]
for k in ListB:
  indices.append(ListA.index(k))

if sorted(indices) == indices:
   print "ListB is in ListA in the correct order"
else:
   print "ListB is not in ListA in the correct order"
```

Comment: ListA = ["C","A","B","C"]
ListB = ListA[1:]
would be shown as not in correct order

Answer (score -1):

Converting the list to string  before the comparison will allow you to do it in **3 lines :**.

**Code**

```
   ListA = [10,2,3,4,5,6,7]
   ListB = [10,2]

   str1 = ' '.join(str(e) for e in ListA)
   str2 = ' '.join(str(e) for e in ListB)

   print(str2 in str1)
```

**output**

```
>>>true
```

Comment: you could just do `print(str2 in str1)`

Comment: Also this gives false positives if `ListA = [10, 2]` and `ListB = [1, 0]` for example.

Comment: You need to compare the length of both lists and assert the shorter joined string `in` the longer joined string or it'll fail. The approach should work for single alphabet string elements but if they're numeric strings, then it would be a poor choice i.e. `['1','12']` and `['11','2']`